# Heroku: Could not load the default credentials (Dialogflow API)

Tags: node.js, heroku, dialogflow-es

I am trying to build a chatbot using Node.JS, Dialogflow & Socket.Io and it works fine on my local machine. But when I want to access my agent from my Heroku app I get this error: Could not load the default credentials.

I have defined the environment variables in the Config Vars on Heroku, but it doesn't seems to work that way. Anyone had this problem before?

Thanks,

Matthieu

Comment: Do you have any example code from what you've written?

Comment: yes, i had it and solved it show us your example code @jvstech